# Can we put a limit for characters entered through CKeditor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I like to put a limit on character entered using ckeditor. I used javascript to limit characters for textarea, But i am unable to limit character when ckeditor is used.i want only 3500 words to be entered using ckeditor afterwards a pop up should say i have reached the maximum limit,Is there any way of doing this??? If ckeditor does'nt support this functionality  , can someone refer any other editor please.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply truncate the string returned to the PHP script with substr ().  If you need to truncate to a word count, then http://www.lullabot.com/articles/trim-a-string-to-a-given-word-count might be a good starting point (though it could use some refinement).

Doing it client-side would require a javascript plugin for the editor.  If this is the case then this isn't really a PHP question but a javascript question.

Comment: my mistake, actually i want to implement it client side, So will you please share that javascript.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a javascript for doing it.  I only ended up on this question due to it being listed as a PHP question.  If CKeditor supports plugins then I suggest you search for a word count plugin or a word limit plugin. http://www.n7studios.co.uk/2010/03/01/ckeditor-word-count-plugin/c might be a good starting point.